# CakePHP - Conditional behaviour not working in find()

Tags: cakephp

I have SubjectGroup, which hasMany Subject.

```
class SubjectGroup extends AppModel {

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Subject' => array('order' => 'Subject.name')
    );

}

class Subject extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array('SubjectGroup');

}
```

I want to get all SubjectGroups, and recursively retrieve their Subjects, but only the Subjects that have a status of 2.

```
$this->SubjectGroup->find('all', array(
    'contain' => 'Subject.status != 2',
    'order' => 'SubjectGroup.name'
));
```

There are no errors, but it just returns all Subjects, even the ones with status = 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally discovered two problems.  I was trying to add an `$actsAs` definition to the controller, to bring in the behaviour. I completely forgot it's not the model.  You have to bring in the behaviour in the controller action.

```
class SubjectGroupsController extends AppController {

    public function index()  {

        $this->SubjectGroup->Behaviors->attach('Containable');

        $subjectGroups = $this->SubjectGroup->find('all', array(
            'contain' => 'Subject.status != 2',
            'order' => 'SubjectGroup.name'
        ));
    }

}
```

But anyway, the condition only seems to work if I use the very basic syntax of:

`'contain' => 'Subject.status != 2'`

Anything more complex doesn't seem to work for me:

```
// DOES NOT WORK
'contain' => array(
    'Subject' => array(
        'conditions' => array('NOT' => array('Subject.status' => 2)),
    ),
)
```

Comment: How come you're not using $actsAs to give the model the containable behaviour in the subject_group.php and subject.php model files, or better still in app_model.php?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the condition for the Subjects more explicitly.

```
$this->SubjectGroup->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'contain' => array(
            'Subject' => array(
                'conditions' => array('NOT' => array('Subject.status' => 2)),
            ),
        ),
        'order' => 'SubjectGroup.name'
    )
);
```

Comment: Didn't work still.  Same thing where it just retrieves all subjects.